How can I limit the size of the web app browser window?
I am learning about flutter, I am developing a web app, I have the following code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'centro/centro.dart';
import 'lado_derecho/lado_derecho.dart';
import 'lado_izquierdo/lado_izquierdo.dart';
import 'navbar/navbar.dart';

class DashboardPrincipal extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        child: NavBarPrincipal(),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Center(
            child: Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minWidth: 1920,
                minHeight: 1080,
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    LadoIzquierdoPrincipal(),
                    CentroPrincipal(),
                    const LadoDerechoPrincipal(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

I need that if the user wants to make the browser window smaller than 1920 * 1080, they cannot, I was looking for how to do it and this is the way it should work, but when testing it if it allows me to make it smaller
I need that if the user wants to make the browser window smaller than 1920 * 1080, they cannot, I was looking for how to do it and this is the way it should work, but when testing it if it allows me to make it smaller

A Macbook is 1440x900. I'd be pretty annoyed if this worked. Fundamentally, it's my browser, not yours; use a media query to display a message to the user, perhaps.

I understand what you mean, but if it is deployed in a private environment and all users have the same screen, that wouldn't matter much
